# Mockito error : "Wanted but not invoked:.. However, there were other interactions with this mock"

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, powermock

Im getting the following error, when I try to mock overloaded methods by passing casted values .

For example in order to mock 
`ABCClass.logWarn(Logger log,String , String description, Throwable e);`

Im doing

```
`ABCClass.logWarn(null,WarningString, description, (Throwable)null); 
...\\ The rest of the methods are standard...
verify(event).setStatus((Throwable)null);//**Line 76**
```

But when I run my test cases Im getting the following error

```
  ABCClassTest.testLogWarn:76 
    Wanted but not invoked:
    MockEvent.setStatus(null);
    -> at com.path.ABCClassTest.testLogWarn(ABCClassTest.java:76)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:.....
```

Why is `setStatus(null)` expected to be called, even after specifically calling the
`setStatus((Throwable)null);`?

**Additional Detail**

Definition of logWarn

```
private static void logWarn(String eventType, String eventName, String errMsg, Throwable e) {

        AnEvent event = AnEventFactory.create(eventType);
        event.setName(eventName);
        if(e!=null)
            event.setStatus(e);//so this is never called if the throwable is null.
    //How do I modify the verify behavior?
        /*
                   Bleh */


        event.completed();
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Being new to Mockito I didnt quite realise what I was looking for. But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862659/how-to-verify-that-a-specific-method-was-not-called-using-mockito) is precisely what I wanted.
Hope this helps anyone else stuck with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Casting doesn't change the object that a variable refers to.  It just makes the compiler not complain when you use the variable in a way that doesn't match its type.  So you really are passing `null` into `setStatus` following your `verify`.

Of course, if you're asking why `setStatus` isn't actually called by the code that you're testing, you'd need to post it before anyone can tell you.

Comment: I think your answer makes sense. Ive added the code about the `logWarn` method, that actually does not call the `setStatus` if the argument passed is Null.

Comment: @DavidWallace.Ive added more detail to the question. Any thoughts?

Comment: So I don't understand your question.  Your code clearly doesn't call `setStatus` when `e` is null.  You've got a `verify` that asserts that it **does** get called; and naturally, that `verify` fails.  What do you feel isn't working right?

Comment: Sorry for the noise. I found exactly what I was looking for here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862659/how-to-verify-that-a-specific-method-was-not-called-using-mockito

Comment: OK, your question never said that you were looking to verify that your method was NOT being called.  I have voted to close your question as "unclear" - anyone who has your precise problem would probably be better off not to find this question.

Comment: Actually EVEN if I called it, the `Status` would never be set because of the `if (e!=null)` clause around setting it.And since I was  passing in a `null` I couldnt expect it to be called.