# Mockito - verify object not invoked at all

Tags: java, mockito

How can you verify a mocked object is not invoked at all? I am trying to test the empty implementation of an interface method using Mockito.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes but the only approaches I know of (using mockito with verify) are on a per method basis - not a blanket for all methods statement

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to verify that a specific method was not called using Mockito?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862659/how-to-verify-that-a-specific-method-was-not-called-using-mockito)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Mockito API Article 7. Making sure interaction(s) never happened on mock

Comment: Mockito.verifyZeroInteractions(jdbc); thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

I use `org.mockito.Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions`.

In fact, personally, I always include this section in all my Mockito tests:

```
@After
public void after() {
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(<your mock1>, <your mock2>...);
}
```

So it acts as a handy catch-all to ensure that the test has no left-over, unexpected invocations that I haven't specifically verified.
I find that more useful than cluttering the tests with specific `verifyZeroInteractions`.