# mockito verify a mehod not called with a parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have this code snippet in the SUT:

```
public void sutMethod() {
    if (model == null) {
        dao.save(model);
    }
}
```

I know that the model will not be null as model already exists. So I want that the `dao.save()` should not be called with model. Hence I need some way of `Mockito.verify` that the method was not called with this parameter. Now I know how to do the opposite: how to make sure / verify that `dao.save()`, or any method per se, is called with a parameter with the help of `ArgumentCaptor`, but not sure about the current scenario. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify that a specific method was not called using Mockito?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862659/how-to-verify-that-a-specific-method-was-not-called-using-mockito)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Mockito.never()`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#never()):

```
 verify(mock, never()).someMethod();
```

Comment: Perfect! that is what I wanted. I was carried too much away by argument captor that I just overlooked this possibility. Thanks