# Verify method with Object argument not called using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, mockito

I have a method with signature `public void save(Object object)` in class `DatabaseService`.

I have a code block that invokes the method:

```
databaseService.save(bypassCode)
if(condition to check if user details have been changed) {
    databaseService.save(user)
}
```

If I want to test that databaseService.save(user) was not called, then how do I do it with Mockito (version 3.3.3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could do something like:

```
Mockito.verify(databaseService, Mockito.never()).save(user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Question has already been answered with several options

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.never;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

// ...

verify(dependency, never()).someMethod();
```

or

```
verifyZeroInteractions(yourMock)
```

[How to verify that a specific method was not called using Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862659/how-to-verify-that-a-specific-method-was-not-called-using-mockito)