# How to test void using Unit Test?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing

I have the following method and I wrote a *unit test* in Java for this method. It is coveraged except from the `if` statement and I also need to test this part.

```
@InjectMocks
private ProductServiceImpl productService;

public void demoMethod(final List<UUID> productUuidList) {
    if (productUuidList.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    final Map<ProductRequest, PriceOverride> requestMap = getPriceRequests(uuidList);
    productService.updateByPriceList(priceRequestMap, companyUuid);
}
```

However, as the method execution is finalized and does not return anything when `uuidList` is empty, I cannot test this `if` block.

So:

1. How can I test this `if` block?
2. Should I create a new Unit Test method for testing this `if` block? Or should I add related assert lines to the current test method?

***Update:*** Here is my test method:

```
@Test
public void testDemoMethod() {
    final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    final List<Price> priceList = new ArrayList<>();
    final Price price = new Price();
    
    price.setUuid(uuid);
    priceList.add(price);

    productService.demoMethod(Collections.singletonList(uuid));
}
```

Comment: what is the code you ommitted? chances are, you can test that something in that block is called 0 times, if you use a mock

Comment: No, it is called in this test method, there is no problem on that side.

Comment: @Stultuske Any idea?

Comment: As Stultuske wrote you could try to verify that nothing changed when you call that method with an empty list (and that it actually doesn't break) - it all depends on what the omitted code is doing. If that part cannot be tested, the only thing you could do is verify an empty list doesn't break the test. Besides that, I would create a new test method if you're explicitly testing that case. Don't mix test cases as this will be harder to track.

Comment: @Henry did you actually understand my comment?

Comment: I added the test method. Any idea?

Comment: @Stultuske Amigo? Are you there?

Comment: I wasn't talking about the test method, I'm talking about the code you "omitted" in the code you are testing

Comment: @Stultuske Ok, I also added the other part of the `demoMethod`. I hope there is no missing part remains.

Comment: @Henry Can you also specify the unit testing framework you are using? JUnit? Mockito? etc?

Comment: you can mock priceService, and check that it is called 0 times

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, but how? Any example pls?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-series

Comment: Thanks a lot, actıually I already look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify) page. But I am really confused and did not find a proper example. Because I need to check if there is a zero interaction if the list is empty. Any example pls?

Comment: `verifyNoMoreInteractions(demoService);` seems to be working, but I need to verify this based on a condition. So, how should I use this with that condition?

Comment: Any reply please?

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is that you don't want to test *specific code*, but you want to test *some behaviour*.

So in your case you want to verify that `getPriceRequests` and `priceService.updateByPriceList` are not called when passing in an empty `List`.

How exactly you do that depends on what tools you have available. The easiest way is if you already mock `priceService`: then just instruct your mocking library/framework to verify that `updateByPriceList` is never called.

Comment: Yes, I mocked `priceService` but as I am really beginner for Unit Test, I have really no idea how can I verify that `updateByPriceList` is never called. Any example code pls?

Comment: You seem to be using Mockito. [This question talks how to verify a method is never called.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862659/how-to-verify-that-a-specific-method-was-not-called-using-mockito).

Comment: Thanks a lot, actıually I already look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify) page. But I am really confused and did not find a proper example. Because I need to check if there is a zero interaction if the list is empty. Any example pls?

Comment: @Henry: then re-read the accepted answer, it tells you **exactly** the code to verify a method is never called. If you have a *specific* question about that, then someone can help, but just repeating "I need a sample" is not going to help.

Comment: Accepted answer is for a previous version. I tried `verify(demoService.demoMethod(null), never()).clear()` but not working. Any idea?

Comment: You need to learn to be more precise with your statements. "but not working" is almost worthless as far as a problem description goes.

Comment: `verifyNoMoreInteractions(demoService);` seems to be working, but I need to verify this based on a condition. So, how should I use this with that condition?

Comment: @Henry: the call with an empty list should be its own test method anyway, shouldn't it? If it isn't, you can just put that call into an `if`: unit tests are just normal Java code after all. Edit: actually: you don't want to verify that there are no more interactions with `demoService`! You want to check for `priceService`!

Comment: The point you missed is using `@Spy`  rather than `@Mock`

Answer (score 0):

The point of doing a return in your if condition is that the rest of the code is not executed. I.e., if this `// code omitted for brevity` was to be executed, the method would not fill it's purpose. Therefore, just make sure that whatever that code does, it was not done if your list is empty.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, if the list is empty the next lines of code are not executed. So, how should I test this if block? Any example code pls for the test method?

Comment: Any reply please?

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 choices:

1. Write a unit test with mocks. Mockito allows you to verify() whether some method was invoked.
2. Write a more high-level test with database. When testing Service Facade Layer this is usually a wiser choice. In this case you can obtain the resulting state of DB in your test to check whether it did what it had to.
3. Refactor your code to work differently

Check out [Test Pyramid](http://qala.io/blog/test-pyramid.html) and [How anemic architecture spoils your tests](http://qala.io/blog/anaemic-architecture-enemy-of-testing.html) for more details.

Comment: Accepted answer is for a previous version. I tried `verify(demoService.demoMethod(null), never()).clear()` but not working. Any idea?

Comment: @Henry, Did you mean to write something like `verify(priceService, never()).updateByPriceList(anyObject(), anyObject())`?

Comment: Actually I have no idea as I have no prior experience. ı just want to see an example usage to check zero interaction based on a condition (if a list is empty).

Comment: On the other hand, `verifyNoMoreInteractions(demoService);` seems to be working, but I need to verify this based on a condition. So, how should I use this with that condition?

Comment: @Henry, you shouldn't verify this based on a condition. Ideally tests should be free of conditions. You'd better write 2 separate tests.

Comment: But `verifyNoMoreInteractions(demoService.demoMethod(null))` does not work. So, how can I test that interaction against null parameter?

Comment: Any reply please?