# Verify method not run Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I am new to Mockito. So I need to do this:

I have a method which is not expected to be triggered as part of my workflow. I know to verify if method runs, I can use

```
verify(updateRule,times(1)).test();
```

I tried

```
verify(updateRule,times(0)).test();
```

but this is not working. am I missing Anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: How is it not working? What do you mean is not working?

Comment: Did you try `never()`?

Comment: It's explained here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862659/how-to-verify-that-a-specific-method-was-not-called-using-mockito